# Is this an example of cyclic dependency?

Tags: java, design, object-oriented-design

I'm an undergraduate student and I have this assignment on a Discrete Event simulator. Currently I have completed to the end of v1.2 [here](https://nus-cs2030.github.io/1718-s2/lab2a/index.html). Attached also, is an algorithmic overview.

[image]

I have wrote my code as such to solve the problem at hand. This code passes all given test cases, but I think there is definitely room for improvement in the design aspect. I came up with this code by drawing the problem out and solving it in a procedural manner and then trying to re-design it in OO. Personally I came from a Python background and now I'm learning Java for this module, so I'm still picking up the ropes on OOP design and getting rid of as much "procedural mindset" as much as possible.

Note: I have private access to `RandomGenerator` as I was given a compiled file to work with in my package.

**Main**

```
import cs2030.simulator.DiscreteEventSimulator;

/**
 * Contains main method to start the programme.
 */
class Main {

    /**
     * Starts the Discrete Event Simulator.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DiscreteEventSimulator.start();
    }
}
```

**DiscreteEventSimulator**

```
package cs2030.simulator;

import java.util.Scanner;

/** 
 * Starts off the Discrete Event Simulator
 */

public class DiscreteEventSimulator {
    /**
     * Creates an EventManager to simulate the execution of events.
     * This is done by using Scanner object to take in inputs. 
     * required for a RandomGenerator, then pass those arguments to EventManager. 
     * @param args String[] 
     */
    public static void start() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int seed = sc.nextInt();
        int numServers = sc.nextInt();
        int numWaitingSlots = sc.nextInt();
        int numCustomer = sc.nextInt();
        double arrivalRate = sc.nextDouble();
        double svcRate = sc.nextDouble();
        sc.close();
        double restRate = 1.0;

        EventManager eventManager = new EventManager(numServers, numCustomer, 
            numWaitingSlots,seed,arrivalRate,svcRate,restRate);
        eventManager.doService();
    }
}
```

**EventManager**

```
package cs2030.simulator;

import java.util.PriorityQueue;

/**
 * EventManager class that handles the sequence of Event executions.
 */

class EventManager {

    /**
     * Array of servers that determines the way ArrivalEvents are processed.
     */
    Server [] servers;

    /**
     * PriorityQueue of events to be cleared by the end of the simulation.
     */
    PriorityQueue<Event> events;

    /**
     * Statistics object to keep track of average waiting time of served customers,
     * number of served customers,
     * and the number of customers that left without being served.
     */
    Statistics statistics = new Statistics();

    /**
     * RandomGenerator object to randomise arrival time as well as
     * service time, which is the time to convert ServedEvent to DoneEvent.
     */
    RandomGenerator gen;

    /**
     * Constructs a EventManager that creates the ArrivalEvents of randomised time.
     * from the number of customers, load them into the PriorityQueue.
     * @param numServers the number of servers to be created.
     * @param numCustomer the number of customers to be served, which is
     * also equal to the number of ArrivalEvents preloaded onto PriorityQueue.
     * @param seed intialising value where the random values are generated from
     * @param arrivalRate arrival rate, mu in RandomGenerator constructor
     * @param svcRate service rate, lambda in RandomGenerator constructor
     * @param restRate rest rate, rho in RandomGenerator constructor
     */
    EventManager(int numServers, int numCustomer, int numWaitingSlots
        int seed, double arrivalRate, double svcRate, double restRate) {
        this.events = new PriorityQueue<>(new EventComparator());
        this.gen = new RandomGenerator(seed, arrivalRate,svcRate,restRate);
        double time = 0;
        Customer customer = new Customer(time);
        ArrivalEvent tempEvent = new ArrivalEvent(customer,time);
        events.add(tempEvent);
        for (int i = 0;i < numCustomer - 1;i++) {
            double x = gen.genInterArrivalTime();
            time += x;
            customer = new Customer(time);
            tempEvent = new ArrivalEvent(customer,time);
            events.add(tempEvent);
        }
        this.servers = new Server [numServers];
        for (int i = 0;i < numServers;i++) {
            this.servers[i] = new Server(numWaitingSlots);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Processes the full sequence of ArrivalEvents to calculate statistics.
     * This process is split into a few stages,
     * (i)At the start of each loop, get the first event from the PriorityQueue
     * (ii)prints the profile of the event to signal that we start processing it
     * (iii)current event creates the next event, 
     * with some information on the available servers as well as RandomGenerator
     * in case a DoneEvent can be created from the current event.
     * (iv) If applicable, Statistics are also updated after 
     * the creation of the new event, which will also be added to the PriorityQueue. 
     * (v) prints the statistics after the PriorityQueue is cleared.
     */
    void doService() {
        while (events.size() > 0) {
            Event firstEvent = getFirstEvent();
            System.out.println(firstEvent);
            Event newEvent = firstEvent.getNextEvent(servers,gen);
            if (newEvent != null) {
                newEvent.updateStatistics(statistics);
                events.add(newEvent);
            }

        }
        System.out.println(statistics);
    }

    /**
     * Accesses an event as well as remove it from the PriorityQueue.
     * @return the first event from the PriorityQueue, 
     * according to the Comparator object it was created with.
     */
    Event getFirstEvent() {
        return events.poll();
    }
}
```

**EventComparator**

```
package cs2030.simulator;

import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 * EventComparator class to create a comparison criteria for events.
 */
class EventComparator implements Comparator<Event> {

    /**
     * Compares 2 Events and decides which is smaller, equal or greater.
     * The first key is to check for the earliest time.
     * If there is a tie breaker, customerID is checked instead, 
     * which also hints on the priority of different type of events.
     * @param e1 left event
     * @param e2 right event
     * @return -1 if left event is prioritised over right event. 
     * 0 if there isn't a priority, which will not happen in this case.
     * 1 if right event is prioritised over left event.
     */
    public int compare(Event e1, Event e2)  {
        if (e1.getTime() < e2.getTime()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (e1.getTime() > e2.getTime()) {
            return 1;
        } else if (e1.getCustomerID() < e2.getCustomerID()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (e1.getCustomerID() > e2.getCustomerID()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Bug with code, please check");
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

**Customer**

```
package cs2030.simulator;

/**
 * Customer class that holds customer information.
 */

class Customer {

    /**
     * Counter integer that generates CustomerID in a non-repetitive way.
     */
    private static int counter = 1;

    /**
     * CustomerID  that allows distinguishing between 2 customers.
     */
    private final int customerID;

    /**
     * Time when the customer first arrives.
     */
    private final double time;

    /**
     * Creates Customer.
     * @param time randomised arrival time of customer
     */

    Customer(double time) {
        this.customerID = counter;
        this.time = time;
        counter++;
    }

    int getCustomerID() {
        return this.customerID;
    }

    double getTime() {
        return this.time;
    }

}
```

**Server**

```
package cs2030.simulator;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Server class that redirects the service of customers according to availability.
 * The status of customer service is seen in terms of events that involves customers.
 */
class Server {
    /**
     * Counter integer that generates ServerID in a non-repetitive way.
     */
    private static int counter = 1;
    /**
     * CustomerID  that allows distinguishing between 2 servers.
     */
    private int serverID;





    //TBC to be re-entered

    private ArrayList<Event> serverQueue = new ArrayList<>();

    private final int maxSize;

    /**
     * Creates a server.
     */
    Server(int numWaitingSlots) {
        this.serverID = counter;
        this.maxSize = 1 + numWaitingSlots;
        counter++;
    }

    int getServerID() {
        return this.serverID;
    }

    void addToQueue(Event newEvent) {
        //assert this.serverQueue.size()<=this.maxSize;
        this.serverQueue.add(newEvent);
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the first slot inside the Server has been taken.
     * @return true if first slot has not been taken, false otherwise.
     */
    boolean canTakeServedEvent() {
        return this.serverQueue.size()==0;
    }//its quite special, only 1 value

    /**
     * Checks whether the second slot inside the Server has been taken.
     * @return true if the second slot has not been and the first slot is taken,
     * false otherwise.
     */
    boolean canTakeWaitEvent() {
        int x = this.serverQueue.size();
        return (x>0 && x<this.maxSize);
    }// == qty means false and cant put

    /**
     * Clears up the 2nd slot of the server. 
     * This is done by removing up the 2nd customer to the 1st slot.
     * and replace the 2nd slot with null status.
     */
    void flushDoneEvent() {
        //theDoneEvent should be always at the first slot
        //everything will be pushed forward and auto updated
        this.serverQueue.remove(0); //no Exception?
        //all previous assumptions of the changed state alrdy done, this just qty

    }

    /**
     * Gets the timestamp at which a customer waiting can expect to be served.
     * @return earliest possible time at which waiting customer can be served
     */


    //TBC this is really hard
    double getDoneTime() {
        return this.served.getTime();
    }
}
```

**Statistics**

```
package cs2030.simulator;

/**
 * Statistics class to keep track of total waiting time of customers.
 * the number of customers who left without being served.
 * the number of customers who are served.
 */
class Statistics {
    private double waitingTime = 0;
    private int numLeft = 0;
    private int numServed = 0;

    /**
     * Creates Statistics object using the empty constructor.
     */
    Statistics(){}

    /**
     * Increases the number of customers who are served.
     */
    void increaseServed() {
        numServed++;
    }

    /**
     * Increases waiting time of customers.
     */
    void increaseWaitingTime(double time) {
        waitingTime += time;
    }

    /**
     * Increases the number of customers who left without being served.
     */
    void increaseLeft() {
        numLeft++;
    }

    /**
     * Formats the Statistics to print all information gathered.
     */
    public String toString() {
        double x = waitingTime / numServed;
        return '[' + String.format("%.3f",x) + ' ' + 
            numServed + ' ' + numLeft + ']';
    }
}
```

**Event**

```
package cs2030.simulator;


/**
 * Abstract Event class to enforce polymorphism.
 * Forces its subclasses to have the ability to create the next event
 * and to update statistics.
 */
abstract class Event {
    /**
     * Customer that the event is involving.
     */
    private final Customer customer;
    /**
     * Time at which the event is created, 
     * which may differ from customer arrival time if 
     * it is only created when it is caused to wait by another preceeding event.
     */
    private final double time;

    /** 
     * Creates an Event.
     * @param customer customer that the event is involving
     * @param time time at which event is created
     */
    Event(Customer customer, double time) {
        this.customer = customer;
        this.time = time;
    }


    /** 
     * Creates the next event of parent type based on its original type.
     */
    abstract Event getNextEvent(Server [] servers,RandomGenerator gen);

    /** Modifies information in statistics if required.
     */
    abstract void updateStatistics(Statistics statistics);

    Customer getCustomer() {
        return this.customer;
    }

    int getCustomerID() {
        return this.customer.getCustomerID();
    }

    double getTime() {
        return this.time;
    }
}
```

**ArrivalEvent**

```
package cs2030.simulator;


/**
 * ArrivalEvent class to simulate the act of a customer arriving.
 */
class ArrivalEvent extends Event {

    /** 
     * Creates an ArrivalEvent.
     * @param customer customer that the event is involving.
     * @param time time at which event is created.
     */
    ArrivalEvent(Customer customer, double time) {
        super(customer, time);
    }

    /**
     * Creates the next event based on the availability of servers.
     * The available server will be updated to hold a field of the event 
     * and be involved in the creation of new event.
     * @param servers Array of servers to be checked
     * @param gen RandomGenerator, not used in this case.
     * @return parent class Event, which could be in the form of
     * LeaveEvent, if there are no available servers.
     * ServedEvent, if there exists an available server that is completely free.
     * WaitEvent, if there exists available server and there are no empty servers.
     * null, which won't be reached as it's a Debugging statement.
     */
    Event getNextEvent(Server [] servers,RandomGenerator gen) {
        Server freeServer = getFreeServer(servers);
        if (freeServer == null) {
            return createLeaveEvent();
        } else if (freeServer.canTakeServedEvent()) {
            ServedEvent newEvent = createServedEvent(freeServer);
            freeServer.addToQueue(newEvent);
            return newEvent;
        } else if (freeServer.canTakeWaitEvent()) {
            WaitEvent newEvent = createWaitEvent(freeServer);
            freeServer.addToQueue(newEvent);
            return newEvent;
        } else { //I think the type to reference before polymorphing is impt, dk wrapper thingy
            System.out.println("Bug in ArrivalEvents");
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a LeaveEvent not bounded to any server.
     * @return LeaveEvent
     */
    LeaveEvent createLeaveEvent() {
        return new LeaveEvent(this.getCustomer(),this.getTime());
    }

    /**
     * Creates a ServedEvent bounded to an empty server.
     * @param freeServer the server that is empty.
     * @return ServedEvent.
     */
    ServedEvent createServedEvent(Server freeServer) {
        return new ServedEvent(this.getCustomer(),this.getTime(),freeServer);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a WaitEvent bounded to a partially occupied server.
     * @param freeServer the server that is partially occupied.
     * @return WaitEvent.
     */
    WaitEvent createWaitEvent(Server freeServer) {
        return new WaitEvent(this.getCustomer(),this.getTime(),freeServer);
    }

    /**
     * Modifies information in statistics if required.
     * @param statistics Not used in this case.
     */
    void updateStatistics(Statistics statistics) {
        return;
    }

    /** 
     * Finds the earliest available server based on search results.
     * @param servers Array of servers to be checked.
     * @return Server if an empty server or partially empty server is found
     * null otherwise.
     */
    Server getFreeServer(Server[] servers) {
        boolean hasFoundSlots = false;
        Server choiceServer = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < servers.length;i++) {
            Server newServer = servers[i];
            if (newServer.canTakeServedEvent()) {
                return newServer;
            } else if (newServer.canTakeWaitEvent() && !hasFoundSlots) {
                choiceServer = newServer;
                hasFoundSlots = true;
            }
        }
        if (hasFoundSlots == false) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return choiceServer;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Formats the ArrivalEvent to print out its profile.
     */
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%.3f",this.getTime()) + ' ' +
        this.getCustomerID() + " arrives";
    }
}
```

**LeaveEvent**

```
package cs2030.simulator;

/**
 * LeaveEvent class to simulate the act of customer leaving without being served.
 */
class LeaveEvent extends Event {
    private Server server;

    /** 
     * Creates an LeaveEvent.
     * @param customer customer that the event is involving.
     * @param time time at which event is created.
     */
    LeaveEvent(Customer customer, double time) {
        super(customer,time);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a null object to signal no actual Event type is created.
     * @param servers Array of servers, not used in this case
     * @param gen RandomGenerator, not used in this case
     * @return null object
     */
    Event getNextEvent(Server [] servers, RandomGenerator gen) {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Increases the customer leave count inside statistics.
     * @param statistics statistics to be updated
     */
    void updateStatistics(Statistics statistics) {
        statistics.increaseLeft();
    }

    /**
     * Formats the LeaveEvent to print out its profile.
     */
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%.3f",this.getTime()) +
            ' ' + this.getCustomerID() + " leaves";
    }

}
```

**DoneEvent**

```
package cs2030.simulator;

/**
 * DoneEvent class to simulate the completion of service to a customer by a server.
 */
class DoneEvent extends Event {
    /** 
     * Server that the DoneEvent belongs to.
     */
    private Server server;

    /** 
     * Creates an DoneEvent.
     * @param customer customer that the event is involving.
     * @param time time at which event is created.
     * @param server server that the DoneEvent belongs to.
     */
    DoneEvent(Customer customer, double time, Server server) {
        super(customer,time);
        this.server = server;
    }
    /**
     * Creates a null object to signal no actual Event type is created.
     * Server is being updated with the service time the 
     * next event should adhere to if any.
     * @param servers Array of servers, not used in this case.
     * @param gen RandomGenerator, not used in this case.
     * @return null object.
     */

    Event getNextEvent(Server [] servers,RandomGenerator gen) {
        this.server.flushDoneEvent();
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Modifies information in statistics if required.
     * @param statistics Not used in this case 
     */
    void updateStatistics(Statistics statistics) {
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Formats the DoneEvent to print out its profile.
     */
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%.3f",this.getTime()) +
            ' ' + this.getCustomerID() + " done serving by " +
            server.getServerID();
    }

}
```

**WaitEvent**

```
package cs2030.simulator;


/**
 * WaitEvent class to simulate the act of customer waiting.
 * for another customer to be served by the same server.
 */
class WaitEvent extends Event {
    /** 
     * Server that the WaitEvent belongs to.
     */
    private Server server;

    /** 
     * Creates an WaitEvent.
     * @param customer customer that the event is involving
     * @param time time at which event is created
     * @param server server that the WaitEvent belongs to
     */
    WaitEvent(Customer customer, double time, Server server) {
        super(customer,time);
        this.server = server;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a ServedEvent to signal that the current customer can now be served.
     * Timestamp the current customer is being served is taken from the server.
     * @param servers Array of servers to be checked, not used in this case
     * @param gen RandomGenerator, not used in this case
     * @return ServedEvent
     */
    ServedEvent getNextEvent(Server [] servers,RandomGenerator gen) {
        if (!this.server.canTakeWaitEvent()) {
            ServedEvent newEvent = new ServedEvent(this.getCustomer(), 
                this.server.getDoneTime(), this.server);
            this.server.setWaitEvent(newEvent);
            return newEvent;
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Modifies information in statistics if required.
     * @param statistics Not used in this case 
     */
    void updateStatistics(Statistics statistics) {
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Formats the WaitEvent to print out its profile.
     */
    public String toString() {
        return (String.format("%.3f",this.getTime()) +
            ' ' + this.getCustomerID() + " waits to be served by " +
            server.getServerID());
    }

}
```

**ServedEvent**

```
package cs2030.simulator;


/**
 * ServedEvent class to simulate the start of service to a customer by a server.
 */
class ServedEvent extends Event {

    /** 
     * Server that the ServedEvent belongs to.
     */
    private Server server;

    /** 
     * Creates an ServedEvent.
     * @param customer customer that the event is involving
     * @param time time at which event is created
     * @param server server that the ServedEvent belongs to
     */

    ServedEvent(Customer customer, double time, Server server) {
        super(customer,time);
        this.server = server;
    }
    /**
     * Creates a DoneEvent to signal that the service has been completed.
     * Time taken to complete the service is randomised by RandomGenerator.
     * DoneEvent is created at the new timestamp of current time of ServedEvent
     * added to the randomised service time.
     * @param servers Array of servers to be checked, not used in this case
     * @param gen RandomGenerator, to randomise service time
     * @return DoneEvent
     */

    DoneEvent getNextEvent(Server [] servers,RandomGenerator gen) {
        double x = gen.genServiceTime​();
        DoneEvent newEvent = new DoneEvent(this.getCustomer(), 
            this.getTime() + x,this.server);
        this.server.setServedEvent(newEvent);
        return newEvent;
    }

    /**
     * Increases the customer served count in statistics.
     * and increase the waiting time by the customer if any
     * @param statistics statistics to be updated
     */
    void updateStatistics(Statistics statistics) {
        statistics.increaseServed();
        statistics.increaseWaitingTime(this.getTime() - this.getCustomer().getTime());
    }

    /**
     * Formats the ServedEvent to print out its profile.
     */
    public String toString() {
        return (String.format("%.3f",this.getTime()) + ' ' +
            this.getCustomerID() + " served by " + server.getServerID());
    }
}
```

The Main dilemma:

1. I created 2 classes `Event` and `Server` to complete the assignment (shown in the link above). I was kind of forced to put a property of `Server` into `Event` so that events could print the profile easily as part of the assignment criteria, but I was also forced to put a property of `Event` into `Server`, as I find that it would save me a lot of work to communicate to the `WaitEvent` in Server of what time to switch to when becoming a `ServedEvent`. Is this a form of cyclical dependency(a bad practice), and if it is, is it justifiable to do so?

Other dilemmas:

2. About the link between class responsibilities and what is the best way of invoking a method call between different objects in different scopes.

   `EventManager` is deemed to be in charge of holding a `Statistics` field, and holding a `PriorityQueue` of `Events`, since it's the Manager. In my implementation I could have written one of the following:

   A: `newEvent.updateStatistics(statistics)`

   B: `statistics.updateStatistics(newEvent)`

   In A, to make a method for the Event class feels easier and more accessible in terms of code length. Each subclass of Event will have their own version of updating the statistics and hence avoid some dispatching on the type of the different classes, which I believe is the principle of OOP if I'm not wrong on this.

   On the other hand, in B feels like its more fulfilling to responsibility. The object `newEvent` is the provider of the information, hence should be placed in the arguments.

   I chose A in the end as during the time I found B logical, I realized I have to do ugly dispatching and I am tempted to pass back statistics as arguments to Events, in the form of `newEvent.f(this)`, in Statistics method `updateStatistics`. This just defeats my purpose of sending `Event`s in as arguments from the start. What is your view on this dilemma of responsibility design vs the ease of coding to the programmer?
3. My assignment requires me to use `RandomGenerator` object, and I decided to implement it as a singleton, created at `EventManager`. However, this object is used at very specific instances in `Event newEvent = firstEvent.getNextEvent(servers,gen)` , which is actually the `Event` reference type to handle all cases by polymorphism, and actually only 2 out of 5 needs to invoke methods of this `RandomGenerator`. Currently, if the problem is simple, I will only need to pass in this singleton `RandomGenerator` object once into a method and 3/5 of the other cases won't use it. But if this 2/5 cases that use it has further branching on sub-cases, would it become ugly to just keep passing this singleton object and have the non-involved cases get access to the `RandomGenerator` methods? Is there any way around this problem?

Comment: Note that unless your asking for different aspect covered by each site, cross posting is generally frowned upon the SE network. Als you should copy the others classes involved in the post.. Furthermore the main point of your question is (according to the title) the point 2, could you eventually put it in first as the main question and eventually let the two others as a complement. Some could say you may even need to split your post into multiple question but I'am not sure. Finally try to list the requirment all together instead of scater them through the post, it will be easier for answerers.

Comment: On helping you with 3. if RandomGenerator is a singleton it doesn't need to be passed around, the polymorphed class that use it should instanciate it. Inner logic in RandomGenerator should make sure they actually don't instanciate more than one.

Comment: @Walfrat noted, I have edited the format of the post

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek Hi, sorry I didn't say that I don't have public access to `RandomGenerator`. I was given a compiled version of it and make done with it, which explains why you won't see the code for `RandomGenerator` here.

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth this remains true, import the compiled on both classes that need it, you don't need to instanciate it on the managing class and pass it afterwards.

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek I mean the fact that I have the compiled version and not the original means that I don't have control over the inner logic of `RandomGenerator`. If its methods that I require are static this would easily solve my problem, but the docs don't suggest it and I don't know how to invoke the methods without creating it somewhere first and have access to its methods anywhere without having access to the object itself.

Comment: Your `Main` class doesn't add much value. Why not just rename `DiscreteEventSimulator.start()` to be `DiscreteEventSimulator.main(String args[])` and have one less source file in your project?

Comment: @SolomonSlow Oh I overlooked that, my `DiscreteEventSimulator` used to be a lot messier and require more classes to be made public, hence the current version, which wasn't updated accordingly.